# Nearest point function from sphere to convex set is surjective onto the boundary of the convex set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a bounded convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)$ is is the nearest point in $A$ to $x$, which is unique because $A$ is convex. I know that $f$ is a contraction (and therefore continuous). I am interested in proving there exists a sphere $S$ containing $A$ (i.e. $A \subset B$ and $\partial B = S$, where $B$ is a ball) such that $\partial A \subset f(S)$.

I have the general idea that there must be a hyperplane containing a point $x \in \partial A$ such that there are only elements of $\partial A$ on one side of the hyperplane, in which case the point $y$ where the line normal to the hyperplane at $x$ intersects $S$ has $f(y) = x$, but I don't know how to prove any of that.

I am using this to prove that $A$ is rectifiable (by proving $\partial A$ is measure zero. I have already proven the continuous image of a measure zero set is measure zero, so we would have $\partial A \subset f(A)$, which is measure zero and thus $\partial A$ is measure zero), so if there is a better way to do that I would be happy to hear. I also don't really know what to tag this, any input would be welcome. I don't have any background in measure theory though, so I would appreciate answers which didn't involve much measure theory.

The definition I was given for a measure zero set is that $A$ is measure zero if for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a countable collection of rectangles $Q_i$ such that $S \subset \bigcup_i Q_i$ and $\sum_i \text{vol}(Q_i) < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Did you consider the sphere which center is the barycenter of the convex set and whose radius is the maximal distance between the barycenter and another point of the convex set.

Comment: Oh, and please rename (with an edit) the convex set to $A$ and the sphere to $S$ please, this is so confusing!

Comment: @OlivierRoche Fixed the variable naming. For the barycenter tip, I see where you are coming from, but I don't know how that would solve the issues I am having.

Comment: First things first. You need to have some actual sphere $S$ in mind that should do the job. I suggest that you take the sphere described above and try to prove it does the job. Call $c$ the center of the sphere and $R$ its radius. All you have to do is to show that for any point $s$ on the sphere, there's a point of the convex set that lies on the interior of the line segment [cs].

Comment: The map $y\mapsto $ closest point in $A$ is a contraction. That is why the image of a set of measure $0$ has measure $0$ (it may not be true for some continuous map).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in \partial A$. There exists a hyperplane $H$ such that contains $x$ and such that $A$ lies on one side of $H$. Let $n$ a normal vector to $H$. The equation of the hyperplane is $n \cdot (z-x)=0$. Now, for every 
$z\in A$ we have $n\cdot (z-x)\le 0$. Therefore, for every $y= x + t n$, with $t\ge 0$  and $z \in A$ we have $\|y-z\|\ge \|y-x\|$, with equality only if $z = x$ (draw a picture and notice an obtuse triangle). So for every point $y= x + t n$ the closest point in $A$ to $y$ is $x$.  Now given any sphere containing $A$, the ray $y= x + t n$ will intersect this sphere ( in exactly one point).  Therefore, for every sphere containing $A$ the map (closest point in $A$) from the sphere to the boundary of $A$ is surjective (it may not be injective, think of a square inside a circle).

$\bf{Added:}$ We can generalize the statement as follows: Let $V$ a finite dimensional normed space with a strictly convex norm. Let $A$ a closed convex set. The map $y\mapsto \phi(y)$-- the closest point in $A$ to $y$-- is well defined on $V$ and continuous. If $y\not \in A$ then $x\colon =\phi(y)\in \partial A$. For every $y'$ in the ray $xy$ we have $\phi(y') = x$. This is easy to see if $y'$ is in the segment $[x,y]$. Otherwise, $y$ is in the segment $[x,y']$. Let $z'$ any point in $A$. Consider $z$ on the segment $[x,z']$ so that $y'z'$ and $yz$ are parallel. $z\in A$ since $A$ is convex. We have $\|y-z\|\ge \|y-x\|$ so $\|y'-z'\|\ge \|y'-x\|$.

Consider now $S$ a compact set surrounding $A$ ( that means $A$ is contained in a bounded component of $V\backslash S$). Any ray $xy$ as above will intersect $S$. Therefore, $\phi(S) = \phi(V\backslash A)$.

Let $x\in \partial A$ and  $y_n\in V\backslash A$, $y_n\to x$. We have $\phi(y_n) \to \phi(x) = x$. Hence $\phi(V\backslash A)$ is dense in $\partial A$. From above we conclude $\phi(S)$ is dense in $\partial A$. But $\phi(S)$ is a compact subset of $\partial A$, since $S$ is compact, and $\phi$ continuous. We get $\phi(S)=A$.